# Why do we tag Reaper of Souls as Diablo 3?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

Looking through the Diablo 3 tags, I noticed that we have a tag for Reaper of Sous on computer, but not console. After looking further, it appears that the tag [diablo-3-reaper-of-souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-reaper-of-souls) links back to [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3). Furthermore, there is simply the tag [diablo-3-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-console), where both Diablo 3 and Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls editions exist on console.

I stopped playing on computer long before the expansion was released, but they must still exist as separate games, otherwise they would not sell each version individually. While the biggest change is going to be content unlocked with the addition of the expansion, and most of the game is the same, they are still two different titles.

I know that on console, the two versions are very different. Questions could be asked about one that would not make sense regarding the other, and questions could be asked where version make a significant impact on the answer.

Why do we tag Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls as Diablo 3?

Comment: The Wikipedia page for Reaper of Souls indicates that it is an expansion pack for Diablo 3. So it probably makes sense to not have it as a synonym, but it seems like we would still want to tag relevant questions with both tags.

Comment: @murgatroid99, it is an expansion, perhaps I should have made that more clear. But we already have expansions listed as separate tags, and questions regarding one does not immediately make it relevant to the other. This is especially the case with console, where the two versions are completely seperate. You do not buy an expansion pack or DLC to upgrade Diablo 3, you just buy Reaper of Souls as a standalone.

Comment: Reaper of Souls on the console isn't exactly "standalone", because it includes the core game as well. You can only buy the core game on last gen consoles and they don't have the expansion at all.

Comment: It is standalone in that the version you purchase, retail, stands by itself. It might include the Diablo 3 content, but it does not register your account as playing Diablo 3 (the core hub recognises the game for the purpose of multiplayer, achievements etc.). The point remains though, @Chippies, they are still seperate games. [Here is a link to the expansion on xbox 360.](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Diablo-III-Reaper-of-Souls/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802394f07d4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The synonym is correct

There is no way to play the original Diablo 3 (with the auction house, trading, and Inferno difficulty) now.  You can only play a special limited version that can't access Reaper of Souls content (e.g. Act V, Adventure mode, and leveling beyond 60).  So every answer that does not involve the new content is true for people playing either the expansion or the original game now.

If we instead made it a true separate tag, people would frequently misuse it.  It would be natural for people playing on a Reaper of Souls account to use that but very few questions are Reaper of Souls specific.  A quick glance at the current questions reveals that only one of the five newest is Reaper of Souls specific (it's about bounties).  So most people who used the tag would do so incorrectly and it would have to be fixed.  The synonym does that automatically.

It might make sense to add a third tag for the expansion on the console.  You can still put in the original disk and play the original game.  But that's not true of the PC.  On the PC, I (only owning the original D3) still play the Reaper of Souls software as that's what the patch did.  I received the Reaper of Souls version in the patch near release day.

So in my opinion, the synonym is the correct approach for the PC version.  There is very little content that should appear only under Reaper of Souls and quite a bit of content that is ambiguous.  Perhaps a new tag should be created for the console version, which goes under the Ultimate Evil edition name.  So something like diablo-3-ultimate-evil could cover just the console version of the expansion.

Comment: This supports what Ive found since, as well. Lord of Destruction, for instance, does not have its own tag. I might fire up my xbox 360 and run Diablo 3 and Reaper of Souls side by side, to make sure its not the case on console. I do remember upgrading to Reaper of Souls specifically due to the great difference it meant to gameplay.